# TipTap useEditor returning null

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, tiptap

I'm using the `useEditor` function from the TipTap library to create an editor, but it returns null at first. What I mean is, if I used `useEditor` and immediately logged the variable I set it to, it returns null, but it returns an Editor object afterwards. I'm using React with create-react-app.

I have this in my App.js file:

```
const editorUse = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("text")) ?? "",
  });
  console.log(editorUse);
```

It prints out this:
[image: error image]

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-darwin-iswww?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line

```
  if(!editor) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <EditorContent editor={editor} />
    </>
  );
```

This is also mentioned in the document.
[Tiptap react doc](https://tiptap.dev/installation/react#3-create-a-new-component)